# Integrating composite function in C

Tags: c, math, numbers, composite, numerical-integration

I am trying to edit a code that uses the trapezoid rule for integrating a function.
My problem is that the program seems to not like the fact that I have more than one term with x involved.

$f(x)=\frac{\beta\gamma}{\delta}e^{-\gamma a}\lr{1-e^{-\delta a}}e^{-\frac{\alpha\beta \mathbf{S}}{\delta}\lr{1-e^{-\delta a}}}$

Here is a picture of the integral I would like to approximate since latex doesn't seem to work:

[image]

I have taken a code from numerical recipes for C (2nd edition) that uses the trapezoid rule:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

double d = 0.7, b = 2.5, g = 1.1, a=0.3; /*One species case: delta, beta, gamma, alpha */
float s1=0.564029; /*s value*/
double exp(double x); /*defining e^x*/

/* Define function here */

double f (double x) { double myresult = b*g/d*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d*x))*exp(-a*b*s1/d*(1-exp(-d*x))); return myresult; }

int main()
{
 float lower, upper, integration=0.0, stepSize, k;
 int i, subInterval;
system("clear");
 /* Input */
 printf("Enter lower limit of integration: ");
 scanf("%f", &lower);
 printf("Enter upper limit of integration: ");
 scanf("%f", &upper);
 printf("Enter number of sub intervals: ");
 scanf("%d", &subInterval);

 /* Calculation */
 /* Finding step size */
 stepSize = (upper - lower)/subInterval;

 /* Finding Integration Value */
 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
 for(i=1; i<= subInterval-1; i++)
 {
  k = lower + i*stepSize;
  integration = integration + 2 * f(k);
 }
 integration = integration * stepSize/2;
 printf("\nIntegral of given function for given values is: %.3f", integration);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

This code gives me errors, I believe because my #Define f(x) has more than one term that involves 'x'.

errors:

```
constant.c:33:18: error: expected ')'
 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
                 ^
constant.c:33:16: note: to match this '('
 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
               ^
constant.c:13:37: note: expanded from macro 'f'
#define f(x)  b*g/d*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d x))*exp(-a*b*s1/d*(1-exp(-d x)))
                                    ^
constant.c:33:18: error: expected ')'
 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
                 ^
constant.c:33:16: note: to match this '('
 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
               ^
constant.c:13:65: note: expanded from macro 'f'
#define f(x)  b*g/d*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d x))*exp(-a*b*s1/d*(1-exp(-d x)))
                                                                ^
constant.c:33:29: error: expected ')'
 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
                            ^
constant.c:33:27: note: to match this '('
 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
                          ^
constant.c:13:37: note: expanded from macro 'f'
#define f(x)  b*g/d*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d x))*exp(-a*b*s1/d*(1-exp(-d x)))
                                    ^
constant.c:33:29: error: expected ')'
 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
                            ^
constant.c:33:27: note: to match this '('
 integration = f(lower) + f(upper);
                          ^
constant.c:13:65: note: expanded from macro 'f'
#define f(x)  b*g/d*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d x))*exp(-a*b*s1/d*(1-exp(-d x)))
                                                                ^
constant.c:37:37: error: expected ')'
  integration = integration + 2 * f(k);
                                    ^
constant.c:37:35: note: to match this '('
  integration = integration + 2 * f(k);
                                  ^
constant.c:13:37: note: expanded from macro 'f'
#define f(x)  b*g/d*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d x))*exp(-a*b*s1/d*(1-exp(-d x)))
                                    ^
constant.c:37:37: error: expected ')'
  integration = integration + 2 * f(k);
                                    ^
constant.c:37:35: note: to match this '('
  integration = integration + 2 * f(k);
                                  ^
constant.c:13:65: note: expanded from macro 'f'
#define f(x)  b*g/d*exp(-g*x)*(1-exp(-d x))*exp(-a*b*s1/d*(1-exp(-d x)))
                                                                ^
6 errors generated.
```

If I only have

```
#define f(x)  b*g/d*exp(-g*x)
```

then it does give the correct approximation for that term.

I have tried to define the three pieces separately, i.e.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

double d = 0.7, b = 2.5, g = 1.1, a=0.3; /*One species case: delta, beta, gamma, alpha */
float s1=0.564029; /*s value*/
double exp(double x); /*defining e^x*/

/* Define function here */

#define f(x)  b*g/d*exp(-g*x)
#define g(x) (1-exp(-d x))
#define h(x) exp(-a*b*s1/d*(1-exp(-d x)))

int main()
{
 float lower, upper, integration=0.0, stepSize, k;
 int i, subInterval;
system("clear");
 /* Input */
 printf("Enter lower limit of integration: ");
 scanf("%f", &lower);
 printf("Enter upper limit of integration: ");
 scanf("%f", &upper);
 printf("Enter number of sub intervals: ");
 scanf("%d", &subInterval);

 /* Calculation */
 /* Finding step size */
 stepSize = (upper - lower)/subInterval;

 /* Finding Integration Value */
 integration = f(lower)*g(lower)*h(lower) + f(upper)*g(upper)*h(upper);
 for(i=1; i<= subInterval-1; i++)
 {
  k = lower + i*stepSize;
  integration = integration + 2 * f(k)*g(k)*h(k);
 }
 integration = integration * stepSize/2;
 printf("\nIntegral of given function for given values is: %.3f", integration);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

But this also gives me an error.

Comment: What error, specifically?

Comment: *This code gives me errors*. It would make sense to show the actual errors. Please paste them exactly into the post.

Comment: start with `exp(-d x)` -> `exp(-d * x)`

Comment: @tstanisl thank you!

Comment: May I ask why are you defining those macroes instead of using some functions? Also, why are you declaring the prototype of `exp`?

Comment: @Bob__ I wasn’t sure how else to do it. Since I’m teaching myself I don’t really know what the best option are. I’m still unable to do infinite limits as I would like to. That was my next step to approach. If you have an idea on how to approach this better I would appreciate any help/hints. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have made a good start. My advice is to define `f` as a function instead of a macro. I.e. something like: `double f (double x) { double myresult = <your expression here>; return myresult; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace all `exp(-d x)` with `exp(-d * x)`.